# Notepad++ regex find-and-replace: Match-but-dont-include operator ?<= doesn't work. Why?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, pcre

I'm trying to employ the find-and-replace dialog of Notepad++ to uppercase en-masse certain parts of an .ssdl file. The configuration I use is this one:

```
Regex: (?i)(?<=[<]EntitySet.*?EntityType="Self[.]).*?(?=")
Replacement Text: \U$1
```

However the ?<= operator which stands for "match-but-dont-include" doesn't seem to be supported or something. Is there a way to make things work? The file I'm targeting is an ssdl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Schema     Alias="Self"
            Provider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            Namespace="Organotiki.Infrastructure.Core.Store"
            ProviderManifestToken="5.7"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl"
            xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator"
            xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation">
  <EntityType Name="dbid">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="DBD_SHORT_NAME" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="DBD_SHORT_NAME" Type="varchar" MaxLength="10" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="DBD_DBTYPE" Type="varchar" MaxLength="1" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="DBD_ENCODING" Type="varchar" MaxLength="1" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="DBD_INST_DATE" Type="decimal" Precision="8" Scale="0" />
    <Property Name="DBD_VERSION" Type="varchar" MaxLength="50" />
    <Property Name="DBD_LAST_UPDATED" Type="decimal" Precision="8" Scale="0" />
    <Property Name="DBD_VERSION_NR" Type="varchar" MaxLength="20" />
    <Property Name="DBD_SW_VERSION_NR" Type="varchar" MaxLength="20" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="gn_setup_vars">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="GSV_GROUP" />
      <PropertyRef Name="GSV_NAME" />
      <PropertyRef Name="GSV_FROM_DT" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="GSV_GROUP" Type="varchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="GSV_NAME" Type="varchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="GSV_TYPE" Type="decimal" Precision="4" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="GSV_VALUE" Type="varchar" MaxLength="512" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="GSV_FROM_DT" Type="decimal" Precision="8" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="GSV_TO_DT" Type="decimal" Precision="8" Scale="0" />
    <Property Name="GSV_NOTES" Type="varchar" MaxLength="200" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="sequences">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="SEQ_NAME" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="SEQ_NAME" Type="varchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="SEQ_NEXT_ID" Type="decimal" Precision="11" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="SEQ_INCREMENT" Type="decimal" Precision="2" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="software_properties">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="SPE_ID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="SPE_ID" Type="decimal" Precision="11" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="SPE_SFT_CODE" Type="varchar" MaxLength="8" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="SPE_NAME" Type="varchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="sw_user_properties">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="SUE_ID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="SUE_ID" Type="decimal" Precision="11" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="SUE_USER_ID" Type="decimal" Precision="11" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="SUE_PROPERTY_ID" Type="decimal" Precision="11" Scale="0" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>
  <Association Name="SUE_SPE_FK">
    <End Role="software_properties" Type="Self.software_properties" Multiplicity="1" />
    <End Role="sw_user_properties" Type="Self.sw_user_properties" Multiplicity="*" />
    <ReferentialConstraint>
      <Principal Role="software_properties">
        <PropertyRef Name="SPE_ID" />
      </Principal>
      <Dependent Role="sw_user_properties">
        <PropertyRef Name="SUE_PROPERTY_ID" />
      </Dependent>
    </ReferentialConstraint>
  </Association>
  <EntityContainer Name="OrganotikiInfrastructureCoreStoreContainer">
    <EntitySet Name="dbid" EntityType="Self.dbid" Schema="niobe" store:Type="Tables" />
    <EntitySet Name="gn_setup_vars" EntityType="Self.gn_setup_vars" Schema="niobe" store:Type="Tables" />
    <EntitySet Name="sequences" EntityType="Self.sequences" Schema="niobe" store:Type="Tables" />
    <EntitySet Name="software_properties" EntityType="Self.software_properties" Schema="niobe" store:Type="Tables" />
    <EntitySet Name="sw_user_properties" EntityType="Self.sw_user_properties" Schema="niobe" store:Type="Tables" />
    <AssociationSet Name="SUE_SPE_FK" Association="Self.SUE_SPE_FK">
      <End Role="software_properties" EntitySet="software_properties" />
      <End Role="sw_user_properties" EntitySet="sw_user_properties" />
    </AssociationSet>
  </EntityContainer>
</Schema>
```

Comment: NPP uses Boost regex engine that does not support unlimited width lookbehinds. Replace with `\K`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPP uses Boost regex engine that does not support unlimited width lookbehinds. Replace with a construction with `\K`:

```
Find:    (?i)<EntitySet[^<]*?EntityType="Self\.\K[^"]+
Replace: \U$0
```

**Details**

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive inline modifier
- `<EntitySet` - a literal substring
- `[^<]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `<` as few as possible
- `EntityType="Self\.` - a literal `EntityType="Self.` substring
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `[^"]+` - 1+ chars other than `"` (as many as possible).

The `\U` makes the text that follows uppercase and the text that follows is `$0`, the whole match.

[image]

Comment: Insightful! Thank you so much!